# Expo: "Can't find variable: BigInt" and "Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered" after deleting yarn.lock and reinstalling

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg-v2

I'm not a react-native expert. But when clone this repo: [deep-links-movie-tutorial](https://github.com/phantom/deep-links-movie-tutorial). I run yarn install then the app built successfully. However, if, after cloning the repo, I delete the yarn.lock file and then run yarn install, I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BigInt
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:203:40 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.1.6:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:137778:3 in global code

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
```

The same thing happens if I copy the entire code to another project.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank!